# API response time discrepancies [Firebase App Client]

Tags: firebase, wifi, firebase-analytics, dynatrace

I am consistently observing a few of the APIs response time metrics. The serverside monitoring gives ~600ms versus the App (iOS) firebase captures response time ~2 seconds for more than 50% of the requests.

I am trying to understand where are the gaps in determining the causes? or there are issues with monitoring tools?

Comment: How do you get the server-side metrics ? We are using Realtime Firebase and get no less than 400ms for a simple get() (direct specific node, not query). Not much realtime to me - had hoped < 100ms.